# How to download a image from URL in App

Tags: android

I'd like to know **how I can download an Image from a given URL and display it inside an ImageView**. And is there any `permissions` required to mention in the `manifest.xml` file?

Comment: Check this nice tutorial for beginner: [Connecting to the Web: I/O Programming in Android](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/39810/1954).

Comment: You must go thru this simply. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to put this `permission` to access the Internet

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

you can try this code.

```
String imageurl = "YOUR URL";
InputStream in = null;

try 
{
    Log.i("URL", imageurl);
    URL url = new URL(imageurl);
    URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConn;
    httpConn.connect();

    in = httpConn.getInputStream();
} 
catch (MalformedURLException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Bitmap bmpimg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
ImageView iv = "YOUR IMAGE VIEW";
iv.setImageBitmap(bmpimg);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use background thread to get image and after getting image set it in imageview using hanndler.

```
new Thread(){
     public void run() {
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL("http://imageurl").openStream());
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.obj = bitmap;
            imageHandler.sendMessage(msg);
         } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         } 
     }
 }.start();
```

Handler code where we set downloaded image in imgaeview.

```
Handler imageHandler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(msg.obj!=null && msg.obj instanceof Bitmap){
            imageview.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable((Bitmap)msg.obj));
        }

    };
};
```

And ofcourse you need internet permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `usage` permission of `INTERNET` in android manifest file and use `java.net.URL` and `java.net.URLConnection` classes to [request](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html) the URL.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [`BitmapFactory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html)-class which can do that. It can create a `Bitmap`-object from an `InputStream`, which can then be displayed in an `ImageView`.

Something you should know is, that using a normal `URLConnection` to get an `InputStream` on a `URL`-object does not always work with the bitmap-factory. A work-around is presented here: [Android: Bug with ThreadSafeClientConnManager downloading images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630258/android-problem-bug-with-threadsafeclientconnmanager-downloading-images)

Answer (score 0):

look this:

Option A:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    try {
        URL aURL = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(is));
        bis.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return bm;
}
```

Option B:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        input.close();
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Jus run the method in a background thread.