# How can I display preview of images from online link in an android application?

Tags: android, file-upload

I am working on an application in which I have to show the preview of image attachments, I have online path of the images. How can I show the preview of the image from that path in android application?

Comment: see this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763841/how-to-download-a-image-from-url-in-app/7763913#7763913

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have images, you have to hit the server to get them. What I suggest to run  AsyncTask and get that image and show it as you want.